# Does Flash CS5 automatically embed font characters?

Tags: flash, text, flash-cs5

Does Flash CS5 automatically embed font characters? I use dynamic text for
flashEff but they dont change.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to embed the chars individually where needed, even if Flash is doing any embedding on its own. Once a char gets embedded it will not rise your file size even if you embed it again.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to [take care of embedding the font](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSb03e830bd6f770ee21a3597d124daee0526-8000.html) yourself.

Comment: when I publish, the text shows fine. there is no longer an option to add the characters in the text field, so i dont know whether its automatic.

Comment: Without embedded fonts, the text will only show fine on machines which have the same font installed. Otherwise, the Flash player will substitute other fonts.  When you select embed font in the properties panel, a new font symbol is created in the library.  Double-click it - you'll find the character options there.